# Problem in configuring Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, configuration-management

I am trying to install Oracle 11g.But, I am unable to configure `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Getting like below

```
root@madhu-Lenovo-G500:/home/madhu# sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
root@madhu-Lenovo-G500:/home/madhu#
```

I didn't get any configurations

Can any one help me?

Comment: If you are trying to edit a conf file try this out: `sudo gedit /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Comment: Actually,I am not trying to edit. I am trying to install oracle for that i need to configure the port,username and password.But,When i gave sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure i didn't get any thing

Comment: ah Ok, can you try changing the file type to make it executable: `chmod u+x oracle-xe configure`

Comment: I tried that getting like.root@madhu-Lenovo-G500:/etc/init.d# chmod u+x oracle-xe configure
chmod: cannot access ‘configure’: No such file or directory

Comment: ok so when you are in `\etc\init.d\`  does that file exist when  you run an `ls`?

Comment: Can you run `ls` in that directory and post in your question your findings?

Comment: Yes, \etc\init.d\oracle-xe is existed

Comment: Ok so what happens if you try `\etc\init.d\o` then hit tab (remember tab has an auto-fill in terminal)

Comment: I hit tab its comming like \etc\init.d\oracle-xe

Comment: Now i am getting like  sudo: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I researched this further and I believe this is what you need to do. Type this command in the terminal.

To change the password for oracle:

```
passwd oracle
```

Then try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Originally, I thought it had something to do with changing the filetype. Boy, was I wrong. :)

Comment: I am getting like   sudo: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe: command not found

Comment: Ok can you `su` as root and then try to run `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Comment: Actually,I am already in root.If i gave with sudo getting like command not found.If i gave without sudo getting like permission denied

Comment: Can you run an `ls -la` and post the results in your question?

Comment: For oracle-xe only getting like -rw-------   1 root root   228 Jul  2 15:25 oracle-xe

Comment: Can you try `sudo vim /etc/inid.d/oracle-xe`?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I managed to resolve it by setting the execute permission for the `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe` file.